# cant install pip pypcap

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, pip

```
pip install pypcap
```

i want to run the MITMf and it requires pycap to run
when i try to install it, this is the error it get, first i tried the

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

then i tried installing it manually with

```
pip install pypcap
```

this is the output i get...
https://pastebin.com/RWWXzdLf

these are my python versions..

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/…/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf]
└─# python3 --version                                                                           1 ⨯
Python 3.9.1+
                                                                                                    
┌──(rootkali)-[/home/…/Desktop/Hacking/MITMf/MITMf]
└─# python --version 
Python 2.7.18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check the following?

1. Do you have pip/pip3 installed in your Kali?
2. Have you tried installing it via sudo?
3. Are you sure to use .txt file instead of .py extension?

I hope that I could help. Good luck troubleshooting!

Comment: yes, i have done and tried all.. but didn't work..
but this command worked fine and installed it fine!
pip install -e git+https://github.com/sburns/PyCap.git#egg=PyCap